# create nested array with PHP

Tags: php

i have a problem here. so, i try to make nested array for my json using php and this is what im getting

```
[
  {
    "ID":"3301",
    "NAME":"cust 01",
    "ID2":"33"
   },
   {
    "ID":"3301",
    "NAME":"cust 01",
    "ID2":"33"
   }
 ]
```

but i want to make it like this

```
[
  {
    "ID":"3301",
    "NAME":"cust 01",
     "attribut":
     [
       {
         "ID2":"33"
       }
     ]
   },
   {
    "ID":"3301",
    "NAME":"cust 01",
    "attribut":
     [
       {
         "ID2":"33"
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

this is the code

```
//Query
$sql = 'select * from mytable';
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
$output[]=$data;
// json
echo json_encode($output);
```

can someone help me?

Comment: We can't help you fix your code if you don't post it.

Comment: Is `attribut` always just an array with one element? If so, change `'ID2' => $value` to `'attribut' => [['ID2' => $value]]`

Comment: @Barmar im sorry, i already update my question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `ID2` value into the nested array in the `attribut` key before pushing onto the `$output` array.

```
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data['attribut'] = [['ID2' => $data['ID2']];
    unset($data['ID2']);
    $output[]=$data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
$str = '[
  {
    "ID":"3301",
    "NAME":"cust 01",
    "ID2":"33"
   },
   {
    "ID":"3301",
    "NAME":"cust 01",
    "ID2":"33"
   }
 ]';
        $arr = json_decode($str,true);
        $ret =[];
        foreach ($arr as $item){
            $res = [];
            $res['ID'] = $item['ID'];
            $res['NAME'] = $item['NAME'];
            $temp['ID2'] = $item['ID2'];
            $res['attribut'][]=$temp;
            $ret[] = $res;
        }
        var_dump(json_encode($ret));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).